# Use height:100% inside a div with aspect-ratio set - bug in certain browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser, aspect-ratio

Note: This question about a new feature in CSS: `aspect-ratio`. Most of the questions on this site with similar keywords are about very different techniques.

Ok so there's a div with the following properties set: `width`, `aspect-ratio`, & `max-height`. Inside of it is another div with `height: 100%`. Works great in desktop chrome & desktop firefox. Does not work in desktop safari, mobile safari, or mobile chrome.

Here's how it should look (or at least does look in desktop Chrome):
[image]

Here's how it looks in mobile Chrome:
[image]

Here's the code ([jsbin here](https://jsbin.com/yerubit/edit?html,output)):

```css
    div {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .con3 {
      border: 4px solid black;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
    }
    .con2 {
      border: 4px solid violet;
      width: 100%;
      aspect-ratio: 9 / 16;
      max-height: 100%;
    }
    .con1 {
      border: 4px solid skyblue;
      height: 100%;
      aspect-ratio: 9 / 16;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="con3">
    <div class="con2">
      <div class="con1">
        hi
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Curious about:

1. Anyone aware of what's happening here?
2. Is there an existing bug filed about this?
3. Have any work-arounds that keep the use of `aspect-ratio` on the parent?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I've found is to use position:absolute on the child.

```css
.con2 {
  position: relative;
}
.con1 {
  position: absolute;
}
```